# Python datetime - column with 2 date formats being (H:M:S) when time >1 hr, and (M:S) when time <1 hr - how to parse

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I scraped a dataset of running finishing times, which includes runners finishing under the hour and above the hour. Runners under the hour are coded like M:S e.g. 48:12 for a runner who finished in 48 mins and 12 seconds. Runners above the hour are coded like H:M:S e.g. 1:12:45.

Is there a way to pass two formats to datetime and have it encode all of them as H:M:S?

I tried:

```py
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'],format="%H:%M:%S")
```

this (rightly) gives an error for runners under the hour.

```py
for obs in range(1,len(df)):
    text = df.iloc[obs].loc['Time']
    for fmt in ('%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S'):
        try:
            datetime.strptime(text, fmt)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    raise ValueError('no valid date format found')
```

This gives the valuerror that no valid format was found.

I want the solution to be something I can use for different datasets so just finding the first runner over the hour and using a different format from then on doesn't really work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['1:01:02', '3:20', 'xyz']})

tmp = (df.Time
         .str.extract('(\d*):?(\d+):(\d+)$')
         .replace('',0).astype(float)
      )
```

which gives you

```
     0    1     2
0  1.0  1.0   2.0
1  0.0  3.0  20.0
2  NaN  NaN   NaN
```

and you can get total number of seconds by:

```
tmp[0] * 3600 + tmp[1] * 60 + tmp[2]
```

from which, you can convert to `timedelta` type.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.to_timedelta` (or `pd.to_datetime`), but first ensure the time is in the 'HH:MM:SS` format by padding it appropriately.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['1', '8:12', '48:11', '1:12:13', '123:12:12']})

fill = '00:00:00'
s = df.Time.str.len()

pd.to_timedelta([fill[0:x] for x in np.clip(len(fill)-s, a_min=0, a_max=None)] + df.Time)
```

#### Output

```
0   0 days 00:00:01
1   0 days 00:08:12
2   0 days 00:48:11
3   0 days 01:12:13
4   5 days 03:12:12
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```